# Retrieving return value of a method in IDE

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I would like to know if there is a way to find out the return value of a method return. The return statements are complex expression evaluations, and I would just like to know what the return statement returns.

I use PhpStorm and Eclipse so whichever one has that type of feature am okay with it.

Comment: You want to hint the result or you want to find out what type is returned in reality? The latter one could be difficult, because for example in php that is float, even if it's basically just an integer: `return 1.0 * 2;`. PhpStorm has good cabability of detecting return types, just automatically create the phpdoc-part: type `/** [enter]` before the method name.

Comment: I would like to hint the result, or even possible show the return value. I am currently working a framework where there are ten function results deep and its slows down the debugging process to manually see which function returned what?